# Python How to update combobox values while writing?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, tkinter-entry

I want to have a list of values that is updated when I edit the text on the upper text field of the ComboBox, but I have found no option to access the value of this text field.

I came up with a kind of ridiculous solution, consisting in an Entry Box stamped over the ComboBox header, so I can edit the Entry Box and bind it to get its value to update the ComboBox.

How can I do this better?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def Run(size=(300,100)):
    a_set=('one','two','three')
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.geometry(str(size[0])+'x'+str(size[1]))
    lista=tk.ttk.Combobox(master,width=22,values=a_set)
    lista.grid(row=0,column=0)
    def update(event):
        a=event.widget.get()
        newvalues=[i for i in a_set if a in i]
        lista['values']=newvalues
    entry=tk.Entry(master)
    entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',update)
    entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
    master.mainloop()
Run()
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement Autocompletion?

Comment: @Sujay No. In the code I'm writting the values of the ComboBox are by the hundreds. I just need to make the value list smaller when I type some letters or words.

Comment: Please check my answer if it solves your issue

Comment: @Sujay Oh I'm sorry, indeed I had imported ttk separately, just forgot to included in my sample code. My bad. What you did is excactly what I want to do. I'd just like to be able to write in the ComboBox's header, instead of having to include a separate Entry Box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the textvariable option of the `combobox`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def update(*args):

    newvalues=[i for i in a_set if var.get() in i]
    lista['values']=newvalues

    
a_set=('one','two','three')
master = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var.trace('w', update)

lista = ttk.Combobox(master, width=22, textvariable=var)
lista.grid(row=0,column=0)
   

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. I read somewhere that textvariable was useless and didn't dig deeper on that line XD.

Answer (score 1):

Here. I think you are trying to implement autocompletion. For `ttk`, you  have to import it separately.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def Run(size=(300,100)):
    a_set=('one','two','three')
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.geometry(str(size[0])+'x'+str(size[1]))
    lista=ttk.Combobox(master,width=22,values=a_set)
    lista.grid(row=1,column=0)
    def update(event):
        a=event.widget.get().lower()
        newvalues=[i for i in a_set if a in i]
        lista['values']=newvalues
    entry=tk.Entry(master)
    entry.bind('<KeyRelease>',update)
    entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
    master.mainloop()
Run()
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, indeed I had imported ttk separately, just forgot to included in my sample code. My bad. What you did is excactly what I want to do. I'd just like to be able to write in the ComboBox's header, instead of having to include a separate Entry Box