# Tkinter Combobox/DropDown search possibilities

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python Tkinter code with some dropdown /combobox entries. Right now, I am flexibel to use both.

I have a list with a lot of possible values, and it does not make sense for the end-user to scroll through the list. Is there any chance to actually start typing the first letters and reduce the list - without having to add a list box?

Just wonder if there is an auto-of-the box solution, or I really need to write the whole LIKE function.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python How to update combobox values while writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448886/python-how-to-update-combobox-values-while-writing)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for: Here i need to write and then I can click on the arrow, and see the reduced list. What i would like is to be the dropdown /combo staying open when I type. I think it would look more userfriendly.. I hope you know what I mean

Comment: Seems like what you need is something like an entry and a listbox

Comment: actually this is exactly what I dont want, from a UI point of view it just look bad!

Comment: @startingover combine both in a custom widget class

Comment: @startingover You can create a custom widget using an entry and a listbox and `place` the listbox below the entry when the user types to show possible values and hide it when the entry loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

Have code for you,

Try this.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lst = ('startingover','Matiiss', 'supra', 'Toyota', 'martineau','Brian','Oakley', 'checkkey')

def checkkey(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    
    if value == '':
        data = lst
    else:
        data = [item for item in lst if value.lower() in item.lower()]
                                    
    update(data)

def update(data):
    lb.delete(0, 'end')

    for item in data:
        lb.insert('end', item)

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', checkkey)

lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.pack()
update(lst)

root.mainloop()
```

Output user types startingover:

[image]   [image]  [image]